# Can text that has been distorted with an envelope be copied and pasted in that format?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

Is it possible to take text that has been distorted using an envelope and copy and paste it into another file maintaining the shape?

When I hit command+C command+V I am getting a grey fill in the shape of the envelope but no text.

I am new to Illustrator and have been trying to figure this out (or find an answer online) for the past few hours.

While I am at it, is it possible to edit said text once it has already been distorted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. Envelopes remain consistent when copy/pasting between AI files.

However, pattern fills *can* and *will* shift when copy pasting in some versions of AI. I reported the bug years ago and it still happens.

Comment: I should have been more clear, how would you go about doing the copy/paste.  When I hit command+C command+V I am getting a grey fill in the shape of the envelope but no text.

Comment: What if you command-G first?

Comment: You should not need to group things. Make certain you are selecting the entire envelope with the Selection Tool (the black arrow, not the white one)